# Highest number in array of objects with criteria

Tags: javascript

In this array of objects, how could I find the highest `groupAvgNum` where `gradeGender == '7G'`?

There probably won't ever be more than 40 objects so I could just loop through each object. Is there a faster way?

```
[
  { groupID: '27093', gradeGender: '6B', groupAvgNum: 4.75 },
  { groupID: '27159', gradeGender: '6G', groupAvgNum: 6 },
  { groupID: '27094', gradeGender: '7B', groupAvgNum: 10.13 },
  { groupID: '27182', gradeGender: '7G', groupAvgNum: 10.38 },
  { groupID: '27179', gradeGender: '7G', groupAvgNum: 7.25 },
  { groupID: '27184', gradeGender: '7G', groupAvgNum: 7.13 },
  { groupID: '27183', gradeGender: '7G', groupAvgNum: 5.5 },
  { groupID: '27100', gradeGender: '8B', groupAvgNum: 5.13 },
  { groupID: '27101', gradeGender: '8B', groupAvgNum: 7.63 },
  { groupID: '27103', gradeGender: '8B', groupAvgNum: 7.25 },
  { groupID: '27187', gradeGender: '8G', groupAvgNum: 6.5 },
  { groupID: '27188', gradeGender: '8G', groupAvgNum: 4 },
  { groupID: '27186', gradeGender: '8G', groupAvgNum: 9 }
]
```

Comment: What is the issue with looping, that is what you have to do.

Comment: please share code what you have tried so far

Comment: Trying to find out if that is the best way. 
Did I ask the question incorrectly?

Comment: If you have to check n elements it will always be O(n)

Comment: The question reads like you're trying to find a way that will not involve looping, however as @JonasWilms mentioned, this problem will require you to iterate over the data set in some manner. It doesn't need to be a manual loop (`.reduce()` is a good solution, as mentioned in answers below) but under the hood you'll still be iterating over the full data set.

Comment: That you all. I shall go learn more about .reduce()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use reduce

```js
var a = [{
    groupID: '27093',
    gradeGender: '6B',
    groupAvgNum: 4.75
  },
  {
    groupID: '27159',
    gradeGender: '6G',
    groupAvgNum: 6
  },
  {
    groupID: '27094',
    gradeGender: '7B',
    groupAvgNum: 10.13
  },
  {
    groupID: '27182',
    gradeGender: '7G',
    groupAvgNum: 10.38
  },
  {
    groupID: '27179',
    gradeGender: '7G',
    groupAvgNum: 7.25
  },
  {
    groupID: '27184',
    gradeGender: '7G',
    groupAvgNum: 7.13
  },
  {
    groupID: '27183',
    gradeGender: '7G',
    groupAvgNum: 5.5
  },
  {
    groupID: '27100',
    gradeGender: '8B',
    groupAvgNum: 5.13
  },
  {
    groupID: '27101',
    gradeGender: '8B',
    groupAvgNum: 7.63
  },
  {
    groupID: '27103',
    gradeGender: '8B',
    groupAvgNum: 7.25
  },
  {
    groupID: '27187',
    gradeGender: '8G',
    groupAvgNum: 6.5
  },
  {
    groupID: '27188',
    gradeGender: '8G',
    groupAvgNum: 4
  },
  {
    groupID: '27186',
    gradeGender: '8G',
    groupAvgNum: 9
  }
]
console.log(a.reduce((acc, a) => {
  if (a.gradeGender == '7G')
    a.groupAvgNum > acc ? acc = a.groupAvgNum : acc = acc;
  return acc
}, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array.reduce((acc, item) => {
  return item.gradeGender === '7G' && item.groupAvgNum > acc
    ? item.groupAvgNum
    : acc;
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you’re looking for a more readable solution, try using a combination of operations:

```
array.filter(obj => {
  return obj.gradeGender === '7G';
}).sort((o1, o2) => {
  return o1.groupAvgNum > o2.groupAvgNum;
})[0];
```

Note that this is far from efficient for large arrays, although for such a short list other overheads will probably be more significant to the overall performance.

Comment: Sorting just to get the maximum will be slow for a lot of elements (well 40 are definetly not a lot)